# Error Sales invoice line doesn't exit

Tags: navision

I'm getting this error message when printing my report.

I can't figure a way to fix this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your ‘Select’ is showing data from Sales Invoice Line while system is trying to find record in Sales Shipment Line.